# How can I translate what we get in the KeyDown event to a Unicode character?

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

The **KeyDown** event on a TextBox (for example) will process the keyboard event and update the control *before* the **CharacterReceived** event is fired on the **CoreWindow** (in fact, it will do it *before* the **KeyDown** event is fired on the **CoreWindow** as well). The TextBox and other controls also doesn't have any **CharacterReceived** event.

Because of this it is necessary to handle the **TextBox::KeyDown** event to perform filtering or other processing of the keyboard events.

The **KeyDown** event seems to be a direct mapping to the Win32 **WM_KEYDOWN** message, as it gives us the scancode of the keyboard key pressed and a few other things. In WPF and Win32, we'd use the **MapVirtualKey()** function to translate the event information to a unicode character.

How do I do this in Windows RT?

Answer (score 2):

There's no MapVirtualKey function anymore. The only information I've found on this is that you need to keep track of variables such as the shift key (kanji key, etc for foreign languages) with bools, in the keydown and keyup events, and then make a massive switch case that will take in all of the variables and spit out what you'd want for your app. Here's microsoft's page that outlines some basics:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868246.aspx